# Ruby hash of hash initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Consider @data is an array of ActiveRecords with fields *date*, *class*, *name*, and *grade*.  Assuming I want to end up with two hashes, one being a unique set of all the dates per name; the other broken down by class, then date, then name to reveal the grade.

```
dates  = {}
grades = {}

@data.each do |d|
   dates[ d.name ][ d.date ] = ''                              # 1
   grades[ d.class => { d.date => { d.name => d.grade } } ]    # 2 
end
```

1. results in an error:

   > undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass

   `dates[ d.name => { d.date => '' } ]` only stores the last record (does not merge into the older results)
2. doesn't error, but ends with an empty hash `{}`

After getting back into Perl, I've forgotten how to initialize and add to a hash of hashes in Ruby.

---

#### Update

For the first one (*dates*), it looks like I can do the following inside the loop:

```
dates[ d.name ] ||= { d.date => '' }
dates[ d.name ][ d.date ] = ''
```

Looking at the docs, I don't know if this is the proper way to do it, it also seems inefficient, since it will be doing the assignment twice for the first value.  It also would suggest that for each key, I need to declare/initialize the underlying data structure, which would get lengthy the deeper the hash of hashes gets (like the *grades* hash).

---

Source:

```
[{ name: 'greg', class:'science', date:'jan', grade:'a' },
 { name: 'greg', class:'math'   , date:'jan', grade:'b' },
 { name: 'barb', class:'history', date:'jan', grade:'a' },
 { name: 'barb', class:'science', date:'feb', grade:'c' }]
```

*dates* would look something like:

```
{ 'greg' => { 'jan' => '' },
  'barb' => { 'jan' => '' ,
              'feb' => '' 
            }
}
```

*grades* would look something like:

```
{ 'science' => { 'jan' => { 'greg' => 'a' } ,
                 'feb' => { 'barb' => 'c' } },
  'math'    => { 'jan' => { 'greg' => 'b' } },
  'history' => { 'jan' => { 'barb' => 'a' } }
}
```

Comment: let's say @data holds {name: 'alex', date: '2014-14-01 12:22:10'} Then what you want see in output ?

Comment: @Ajay does that help -- all of this is an example made off the top of my head, so excuse me if there are errors

Answer (score 0):

This will actually work, as when you try to access the key from the hash, it not only returns the default but also sets it:

```
Hash.new do |h, k|
  h[k] = Hash.new do |hh, kk|
    hh[kk] = {}
  end
end
```

**Update:**

This might be a little cleaner albeit potentially more confusing for future developers than just checking if nil.

```
dates = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = {} }
grades = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = dates.clone }
```

Comment: So would `h = {{{{}}}}` be appropriate?

Comment: If you just wanted *one* Hash, I'd do: `@data.inject(Hash.new({})) { |hash, el| **do stuff here }`

Comment: `Hash.new({})` is a shortcut to confusion. The default value is **not** cloned.

Comment: Not sure what's worse, *n* level of loops, or *m* checks to see if it's initialized

Comment: For your first hash, you only need one `Hash.new do` that sets the default key to {}. For your second example, you could use one `Hash.new do` that sets the hash's default to a clone of the first, thus giving you the extra level.

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
d={}
c=Client.first
d[c.last_name]=[]
d[c.last_name][c.id]=//your value
```

d[c.last_name]=[], initialize an array of hash for c.last_name

Answer (score 0):

I was able to build the dates hash like this:

```
arr = [{ name: 'greg', class:'science', date:'jan', grade:'a' },
       { name: 'greg', class:'math'   , date:'jan', grade:'b' },
       { name: 'barb', class:'history', date:'jan', grade:'a' },
       { name: 'barb', class:'science', date:'feb', grade:'c' }]


dates = arr.group_by { |x| x[:name] }.each_with_object({}) do |(k, v), hash|
  dates = v.map { |i| i[:date] }.uniq
  dates_hash = dates.each_with_object({}) { |date, h| h[date] = "" }
  hash[k] = dates_hash
end

puts dates

{"greg"=>{"jan"=>""}, "barb"=>{"jan"=>"", "feb"=>""}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

To obtain the unique `:date` values for each `:name`, you could use the form of [Hash.update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (same as `merge!`) that uses a hash to determine the values of keys are are contained in both hashes being merged:

```
def dates_by_name(arr)
  arr.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
    h.update({g[:name]=>[g[:date]]}) {|_,ov,nv|
      ov.include?(nv.first) ? ov : ov + nv}}
end
```

There are many ways to organize the results for grades by class, date and name. The following employs recursion:

```
def grade_by_class_date_name(arr, fields)
  fd = fields.dup
  f = fd.shift
  return arr.first[:grade] if f==:grade
  g = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) { |e,g|
    g[e[f]] << e.reject { |k,_| k == f } }
  g.each_key { |k| g[k] = grade_by_class_date_name(g[k], fd) }
  g 
end
```

**Examples**

```
arr = [{ name: 'greg', class:'science', date:'jan', grade:'a' },
       { name: 'greg', class:'math'   , date:'jan', grade:'b' },
       { name: 'barb', class:'history', date:'jan', grade:'a' },
       { name: 'barb', class:'science', date:'feb', grade:'c' }]

dates_by_name(arr)
  #=> {"greg"=>["jan"], "barb"=>["jan", "feb"]}
```

The hash returned by `dates_by_name` is not in the form you requested, but you could manipulate it easily to suit your requirements.

```
fields = [:class, :date, :name, :grade] 

grade_by_class_date_name(arr, fields)
  #=> {"science"=>{"jan"=>{"greg"=>"a"},
  #                "feb"=>{"barb"=>"c"}},
  #    "math"   =>{"jan"=>{"greg"=>"b"}},
  #    "history"=>{"jan"=>{"barb"=>"a"}}}
```